# FCM push notification can't received, just errors on console

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to make Push notifications using Firebase FCM and PWA.
When I sent a Push notification from the server, it returns a send ID indicating success, but I cannot receive it on my iPhone(Safari).

I connected to my Mac and looking at the debug console, shows the following error.

```
"push event ended without showing any notification may trigger removal of the push subscription."
```

I have looked everywhere and can't find the cause.
Can someone please help me?

I want to receive push notifications

Comment: perhaps your code isn't showing any notification before the push event ended triggering the removal of the push subscription. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - without code, it's just a guess - P.S. search that error message, and you get a wealth of information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "search that error message, and you get a wealth of information" - I search for the error message and this SO post is the only thing that shows up 